# a4j:commandButton dynamic value

Tags: html, jsf-2

I'm using jsf2, making some datatable with filters. Each filter - `<a4j:commandButton>`. But filter must be styled with 2 different styles. For example filter says: "2 rows", so "2" will be big and bold and "rows" will be small and italic.
Maybe this question is simple HTML question, I don't know.

Comment: changing `<a4j:commandLink>` makes it possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `<a4j:commandButton>` generates a HTML `<input type="submit">` element. It is not possible to style parts of its value differently. This is a limitation in HTML. Best what you can do is using an image instead which you set as button's background image by CSS. But this is clumsy when it comes to localization.

Better would indeed be to use an `<a4j:commandLink>`. You've all freedom to style its value the way you want, you can namely nest any HTML/JSF inside `<a4j:commandLink>`. You could always throw in some shot of CSS with borders, backgrounds, etc to make the link to look like a button.